# Python querying CSV column

Tags: python, csv

I'm creating a menu in python and cant seem to get it working on the one section.

my code searches the postcode column from the user `raw_input`.

I want the code to just simply go back to the menu if the `raw_input` does not match a postcode in the customer.csv

Customer.csv

```
1,Lee,test1,dy4zzz,121111111,3,4
2,luke,test2,dy5xxx,854539116,5,6
3,alex,test3,dy1ttt,7894561230,9,8
4,aaron,test4,b65yyy,16464634676974,8,9
```

code from program

```
import csv,os,time,math

def menu():
    print (""" Main Menu
        1.Add New Route
        2.Add Customer
        3.Edit Customer
        4.View Customer
        5.Exit """)
    ch=raw_input("Enter your choice")
    if ch=="1":
        NewRoute("Route.csv")
    elif ch=="2":
        cid=readfile("customer.csv")
        addtofile("customer.csv", cid)
        menu()
    elif ch=="3":
        editrecord("customer.csv")
        os.remove("customer.csv")
        os.rename("temp.csv","customer.csv")
        menu()
    elif ch=="4":
        readfile("customer.csv")
        menu()
    elif ch=="5":
        exit()
    elif ch !="":
        print ("try again")
        menu()



def NewRoute(file_name):
    print "Route Calculator"
    f=open("route.csv","w")#Opens Route file for writing
    f.truncate() #clears all contents from file so a new route can be written to it
    f.close() #saves and closes route file 
    driver=raw_input("Enter Drivers Name: ")
    readfile("customer.csv")
    cur = (0, 0)
    route = [0]
    xy = [ ]
    z= ()
    zz= []
    n = input("Please input the amount of destinations you want to visit:")
    a = range(1, n + 1)
    cidd = []
    record = [1]
    for i in range(n):
        cid=raw_input("Enter Postcode with no spaces and in lowercase:")
        f3=csv.reader(open("customer.csv",'r'))


        for row in f3:
            if row[3]==cid:
                x=eval(row[5])
                y=eval(row[6])
                z=row[1]
                xy.append((x,y))
                zz.append(((cid,z)))
                cidd.append((cid,z))
```

Comment: its the last section of the code and i need something like else statement but only when the user's input equals a postcode in the CSV, then only use that record

Comment: Are there some `import` statements missing from what you've pasted? Trying to get this running in the interpreter.

Comment: yes i have now added them, let me know if you need anything else? or full code via collabit

Comment: This code does not run as provided, it is missing a function - readfile.  But I think your question can be answered without all of that supporting code, I'll take a stab at it below.

Answer (score 1):

If what you really want is to exit if a matching `postcode` is not found, this ought to help.  First, finding a matching postcode is a nice bit of code that may be extracted and placed in it's own function like below.  I'm not sure if postcode is the 3rd record or not, update the REC_ constants as necessary.

```
# Constants for accessing your CSV record (up to postcode)
REC_NUM = 0
REC_NAME = 1
REC_FIELD3 = 2
REC_POSTCODE = 3


def matching_postcode_row(post_code):
    reader = csv.reader(open('customer.csv'))
    for rec in reader:
        if post_code == rec[REC_POSTCODE]:
            return rec
    return None
```

With the matching_postcode_row function written, you can now call it like so:

```
cid=raw_input("Enter Postcode with no spaces and in lowercase:")
rec = matching_postcode_row(cid)
if not rec:
    return
```

As a matter of style, you should rename NewRoute to new_route.  CamelCased names are generally used for classes only.